# Title not show up if their are no blog posts. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

On our current site we have different company profiles. Some companies have blog posts that display on their profile and some don't. Their is an h2 tag above posts that is in the page template then the code to bring in the posts. The code looks like this.

```
 <h2>Recent Blog Articles</a></h2>
 <?php echo get_related_author_posts(); ?>
```

I am trying to find a way so that if their are no posts for the company the h2 tag will not show up. The code in the functions file is

```
function get_related_author_posts() {
    global $authordata, $post;

    $authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );


    $output = ' <ul style="list-style: none;">';
    foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;

}
```

I can not figure it out any suggestions would help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd ask this question over at WordPress Answers. It would fit better there and probably be answered faster. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `h2` to the function you can control the entire output by adding an if statement to check is there are any author posts.

```
function get_related_author_posts() {
    global $authordata, $post;

    $authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );

    if( ! $authors_posts ) {
        return;
    } 

    $output = '<h2>Recent Blog Articles</h2>';
    $output .= ' <ul style="list-style: none;">';
    foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a></li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    return $output;

}
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I struggled with that for a while and it was so simple. You sir are AWESOME.